# Supremum and compact sets

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

> $8$. Show that for any compact set $K$ and any continuous function $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$, $f(K)$ is also a compact set. Deduce that there exists $x^*\in K$ such that $f(x^*)=\sup_{x\in K}f(x)$.
>
> $8$. Let $\{A_\alpha\}_\alpha$ be an open covering for $f(K)$. Then $$f(K)\subset\bigcup_\alpha A_\alpha\Leftrightarrow K\subset f^{-1}\left(\bigcup_\alpha A_\alpha\right)=\bigcup_\alpha f^{-1}(A_\alpha)\;,$$ where the last inequality can be proved in a similar way as the one at exercise $4$ for the union of two. We have seen in the lectures that if $A_\alpha$ is open, and $f$ is continuous, $f^{-1}(A_\alpha)$ is also open. Now, since $K$ is compact, there exists a finite subcovering for $K$. That is $$K\subset\bigcup_{j=1}^N f^{-1}(A_{\alpha_j})=f^{-1}\left(\bigcup_{j=1}^NA_{\alpha_j}\right)\Leftrightarrow f(K)\subset\bigcup_{j=1}^NA_{\alpha_j}\;.$$ Then, $f(K)$ is a compact set. Since we know that any compact set is bounded, the completeness axiom for the real line yields that there exists $s=\sup\{f(x):x\in K\}$. *Hence, there exists a sequence* $x_n\in K$ *such that* $\lim_nf(x_n)=s$. But, since $f(K)$ is closed, $s\in f(K)$. Hence, there exists $x^*\in K$ such that $f(x^*)=s$.

I don’t follow the italicized part of the solution just before the end.

Comment: From the definition $s=sup\{f(x):x\in K\}$ we see that for every $n\in\mathbb N,$ there is an $x_n\in K$ such that $f(x_n) \geq s - \frac1n.$ Since we also have $s \geq f(x_n),$ it follows that $\lim_n f(x_n) = s,$ as desired.

Comment: Here is a [MathJax Tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

As $s = \sup f(K)$ and $f(K)$ is bounded there exists a sequence $y_n \in f(K)$ such that $$\lim y_n = \lim f(x_n) = s$$

Just notice that $$s - \frac{1}{n} < y_n \leq s$$

Then as $y_n = f(x_n)$ for some $x_n \in K$, there exists a sequence $x_n \in K$ such that what you sublined is true.

Comment: Should the solution not be $\exists$ a sequence $f(x_n) \in f(K)$ st 

$\lim_nf(x_n)=s$ (rather than a sequence $x_n \in K$) and since $f(K)$ is closed $s \in f(K)$?

Comment: If there exists a sequence in $f(K)$ consequently there will be one in $K$ since $f(K)$ is the image set.

Comment: Why is this neccessary for the solution though?

Comment: To make sure $f$ attains to its maximum. There is a sequence such that $s$ is limit of.

Comment: But this is a sequence of $f(x_n)$ not $x_n$

Comment: Sure, but use the fact that $f$ is continuous what does that give you? Any convergent sequence in $K$ means that $\lim f(x_n) = L$, for some $L$ in the image, that you are taking to be the supremum. Sorry, but I don't understand you question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21070/discussion-between-aaron-maroja-and-usainlightning).